# How can I workaround this Gmail Print sizing bug on a .EML attachment?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, I click on a .EML attachment and Gmail shows:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I do Print and ges:

[image]

which has the right side cropped, hiding the whole date (perhaps due to the warning box).

What workarounds are available?

Scaling down remove the crop but only at the cost of smaller content.

Answer (score -1):

At the Print preview, narrow the window:

[image]

giving (widened for inspection)

[image]

and thence

[image]